# How do I set the values of cells in a table to be values of a text input onclick using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to be able to display data in text inputs and a select input from an existing table, that on click of an edit button (one for each row), the data is inserted. I also want it to use the `this` function (which I'm not confident using) so that only data from the row that is clicked on, is inputted into the text inputs. Currently the values are showing up as undefined. Sorry about the messy code.

```js
function displayStudent(student) {
  let newStudent = 
      `<tr>
          <td>${student.firstName}</td>
          <td>${student.lastName}</td>
          <td>${student.grade}</td>
          <td>${student.email}</td>
          <td><input type="button" value="EDIT" class="editButton" onclick="editStudent(this)"></td>
      </tr>`;
  document.getElementById('studentTable').innerHTML += newStudent;
}
        
function editStudent() {
  document.getElementById("firstName").value = this.document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].value;
  document.getElementById("lastName").value = this.document.getElementsByTagName("td")[1].value;
  document.getElementById("grade").value = this.document.getElementsByTagName("td")[2].value;
  document.getElementById("email").value = this.document.getElementsByTagName("td")[3].value;
}
```

```html
<table id="studentTable">
  <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
      <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="editFields">
  <div class="fields">
      <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
      <input id="firstName" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="fields">
      <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
      <input id="lastName" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="fields">
      <label for="grade">Grade</label>
      <select id="grade">
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="11">11</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
      </select>
  </div>
  <div class="fields">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input id="email" type="text">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not pass `this`, pass `event` and you can get the details of current row and fill the inputs

```
<td><input type="button" value="EDIT" class="editButton" onclick="editStudent(event)"></td>


function editStudent(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("firstName").value = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.children[0].textContent;
    document.getElementById("lastName").value = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].textContent;
    document.getElementById("grade").value = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.children[2].textContent;
    document.getElementById("email").value = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.children[3].textContent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've prepared a more detailed example with ids being generated dynamically and button's name and "onclick" function content changing according to action.

Here also is the codepen view which I've used to edit it:
https://codepen.io/antiqtech/pen/YzZaKGJ

```
    <table id="studentTable">
                            <tr>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>Grade</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                            </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="editFields">
                            <div class="fields">
                                <label for="firstName">First          

    Name</label>
                                <input id="firstName"     
    type="text">
                            </div>
                            <div class="fields">
                                <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                                <input id="lastName" type="text">
                            </div>
                            <div class="fields">
                                <label for="grade">Grade</label>
                                <select id="grade">
                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                    <option value="11">11</option>
                                    <option value="12">12</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fields">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <input id="email" type="text">
                            </div>
  
      <button type="button" id="btnEditUpdate"     
     onclick="insertStudent();">Insert</button> 


    function insertStudent() {
        var student = { firstName: "", lastName: "", grade: "", 
        email: "" };
        student.firstName = 
        document.getElementById("firstName").value;
        student.lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
        student.grade = document.getElementById("grade").value;
        student.email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        displayStudent(student);
    }
    function displayStudent(student) 
    {
        var cc = Math.random(); 
        let newStudent =
        `<tr>
                <td id="fn_` +
        cc +
        `">${student.firstName}</td>
                <td id="ln_` +
        cc +
        `">${student.lastName}</td>
                <td id="gr_` +
        cc +
        `">${student.grade}</td>
                <td id="em_` +
        cc +
        `">${student.email}</td>
                <td><input type="button" value="EDIT" 
        class="editButton"    
                    onclick="editStudent(` +
        cc +
        `)"></td>
            </tr>`;
        document.getElementById("studentTable").innerHTML += 
        newStudent;
        document.getElementById("firstName").value = "";
        document.getElementById("lastName").value = "";
        document.getElementById("grade").value = "";
        document.getElementById("email").value = "";
    }

    function editStudent(val)
    {
        document.getElementById("firstName").value =    
        document.getElementById(
        "fn_" + val).innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("lastName").value = 
        document.getElementById(
        "ln_" + val).innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("grade").value = 
        document.getElementById(
        "gr_" + val).innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("email").value = 
        document.getElementById(
        "em_" + val).innerHTML;

        document.getElementById("btnEditUpdate").onclick = function 
        () {
        updateStudent(val);
        };void 0;  
        document.getElementById("btnEditUpdate").innerHTML = 
        "Update";
    }
    function updateStudent(val) 
    {
        document.getElementById("fn_" + val).innerHTML = 
        document.getElementById(
        "firstName").value;
        document.getElementById("ln_" + val).innerHTML = 
        document.getElementById(
        "lastName").value;
        document.getElementById("gr_" + val).innerHTML = 
        document.getElementById(
        "grade").value;
        document.getElementById("em_" + val).innerHTML = 
        document.getElementById(
        "email").value;
        document.getElementById("firstName").value = "";
        document.getElementById("lastName").value = "";
        document.getElementById("grade").value = "";
        document.getElementById("email").value = "";
        document.getElementById("btnEditUpdate").onclick = function ()             
        {
           insertStudent();
        };
        document.getElementById("btnEditUpdate").innerHTML = 
        "Insert";
    }
```